# Remove the button "locate me" in bing map

Tags: gis, bing-maps

Goal:
Remove the button "locate me" in bing map

Problem:
How do I remove it?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the option in the initialization of the map control using the option `showLocateMeButton`, here is the code:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75),
    showLocateMeButton: false,
    zoom: 5 
});
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt712646.aspx